# How to prove that $c_0I+c_1A+..+C_nA^n$ is singular if $(v,Av,A^2v,...,A^nv)$ is linearly dependent, $v \in \mathbb{F^n}$ and $A_{n \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that the sequence $(v,Av,A^2v,...,A^nv)$ is linearly dependent (1), $A_{n \times n}$, over $\mathbb{F^n}$ prove that scalars $c_0,c_1,..,c_n$ exist (such that not all of them are zeroes) such that the matrix $M=c_0I+c_1A+..+c_nA^n$ is singular.

First I'm not sure how (*) can be used here exactly. We can say that the sequence $(c_0I,c_1A,..,c_nA^n)$ resembles the sequence (1) where $v=I$. But here we have scalar $c_i$ so it's not exactly the same sequence.

Maybe I could say that the sequence $(c_0I,c_1A,..,c_nA^n)$ is linearly dependent because it has $n+1$ elements while over $dim\mathbb{F^n}=n$ $\quad$(2).

Intuitively I understand that suppose we sum all the matrices $c_iA^i$ and then in the last sum operation we get to some $c_jA^j$ and if it's a linear combination of other matrices then we can have such a $c_j$ that:
$$
c_oI+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_iA^i+c_jA^j=0
$$
But I don't think this is enough to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the definition of linear dependence mean? It means there are $b_0,\ldots,b_n$, not all zero, with $b_0v+b_1Av+b_2A^2v+\cdots+b_nA^n v=0$. That means that $Bv=0$ where $B=b_0I+b_1A+b_2A^2+\cdots+b_nA^n$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood: because the set $V=v, v_1A,..,v_nA^n$ is linearly dependent then we have $V=v+v_1A+..+v_nA^n=0$. Then we multiply individual elements of $V$ by $b_i$ and we get $B=b_0v+b_1Av+..+b_nA^nv_n=0$. Because elementary operations (multiplying by $b_i$) don't change anything then we get that $B$ is linearly dependent, right?

Comment: @Yos I'm baffled by your comment. There are no $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. You are given the $n+1$ vectors $v,Av,\ldots,A^nv$ are linearly dependent, so that some linear combination of them, not necessarily their sum, is zero.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I meant: because the sequence $v, vA,..,vA^n$ is linearly dependent then we have $v+vA+..+vA^n=0$. But why $B=b_0v+b_1Av+..+b_nA^nv=0$ is still linearly dependent? Because if we multiply each element in the original sequence with $b_i$ it doesn't change anything right?

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate if you could explain 2 things: why do we know that $b_0v+b_1Av+..+b_nA^nv=0$ and why from the fact that $Bv=0$ we know that necessarily $B=0$.

Comment: @Yos I think you may need to review the definition of linear dependence. For example, if the set of vectors $x, y, z $ are linearly dependent, it does NOT mean that $x + y + z = 0$ (that COULD be true, but the definition of linear dependence does not guarantee that). What it DOES guarantee is that there are scalars $a,b,c $ with not all of them being zero (meaning at least one scalar is not $0$) such that $ax + by + cz = 0$. You should really take a little time and investigate the difference between those two statements.

Comment: @yos Alas you are very confused about the **definition** of linear dependence. Of course, from $Bv=0$ one **cannot** infer that $B=0$.

Comment: So why can we conclude that $B$ is singular?

Comment: @yos please attend to the **definition** of singularity.

Comment: A singular matrix is a matrix in which vectors are linearly dependent or its determinant is $0$. But as far as I understand you're supposing that $b_0...b_n$ exist such that $b_0v+...+b_nA^nv$ is libearly dependent. But what actually proves this?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @Lord Shark's answer. From definition of linear dependence there exists $b_0,...b_n$, not all zeros such that $b_0v + b_1Av + ... + b_nA^nv =0 $. This leads to $Bv=0$ where B = $b_0T + b_1A + ... + b_nA^n$. I think the problem that you are facing is how do we get from this step to saying that B is singular. The reason I marked your other question as duplicate is that you were still asking same question. @Lord Shark's answer is correct but the last connecting part is implicit in his answer and creating new question is not ideal. I will just explicitly state it (Correct me if I am wrong @Lord Shark). Back to your question - how does $Bv=0$ imply B is singular. This is true given that $v\ne0$. If you familiar with null space then existence of $v$ such that $Bv=0$ implies that $rank(B) < n$. If not there is simple way to think about is if $B$ is invertible then you can do $B^{-1}Bv=0$, giving $v=0$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. I'm familiar with null space but why can we say that $rank(B)<n$ because column vectors of $Bv$ are linearly independent and therefore there will be at least one row of zeroes?

Comment: We can say the rank is less than n because the columns of B are dependent. $Bx$ is essentially a linear combination of columns of $B$. This equals to zero implies columns are dependent. I would highly recommend you to return to basics and spend some time solving textbook problems.