# Given linearly dependent set $U=\{x, Bx, B^2x,..,B^nx\}$ where $B$ is $n \times n$ matrix prove that matrix $k_0I+k_1B+..+k_nB^n$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given linearly dependent set $U=\{x, Bx, B^2x,..,B^nx\}$ where $B$ is $n \times n$ matrix prove that matrix $k_0I+k_1B+..+k_nB^n$ is not invertible.

I understand that because $U$ is linearly dependent then $k_0..k_n$ not all zeroes exist such that $k_0x+k_1Bx+..+k_nB^nx=0$.

Then we can factor out $x$ to receive: $Kx=0$ where $K=k_0I+k_1B+..+k_nB^n$.

At this point I'm not sure what to do.

**EDIT:** this question should not be considered a duplicate of [How to prove that $c_0I+c_1A+..+C_nA^n$ is singular if $(v,Av,A^2v,...,A^nv)$ is linearly dependent, $v \in \mathbb{F^n}$ and $A_{n \times n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316222/how-to-prove-that-c-0ic-1a-c-nan-is-singular-if-v-av-a2v-anv-is). Although similar the other question **doesn't** answer the question posed here in particular the other question provides the transitions necessary to arrive to the form $Kx=0$ however it stops short of explaining **why** we can consider $K$ to invertible.

Comment: How are $B$ and $A$ related?

Comment: U is linearly depedent so there exist field elements ko,k1,...kn such that k0x+k1Bx+...+knB^nx=0. then (ko+k1B...+knB^n) has a non trivial kernel element. i don't know this answer is what you want since your statement of the problem is quite vague. i understood that A=B

Comment: @JimmyK4542 sorry just realized I had a typo

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316222/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm aware of that question. Unfortunately you didn't explain the step in which I'm interested so that question will not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $Kx=0$ where $K=k_0I+k_1B+..+k_nB^n$, for a non zero vector $x$. It means that the kernel of the matrix is not empty. And so it cannot be invertible (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).